# How to Retain an Active Tab's Focus with Bootstrap 5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I see examples on how to retain an active tab's focus after refreshing the browser in Bootstrap 4 and below, but nothing for Bootstrap 5.

I'm not able to use the examples from Bootstrap 4 when using Bootstrap 5 tabs.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target=

"#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">Home tab content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">Profile tab content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab" tabindex="0">Contact tab content</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0czektof/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 changed a lot compared to Bootstrap 4.

Make use of the example from [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#via-javascript).

There are some errors in your code related to the fact that you used an example of an older version.

- Your querySelector uses `a`-elements but your HTML makes use of `button`-elements.
- You use a wrong attribute selector. Bootstrap 5 uses `data-bs-toggle` not `data-toggle`.
- Bootstrap 5 doesn't add .tab() function anymore. It uses his own global object to manage stuff.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem('activeTab', e.target.dataset.bsTarget);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("localstorage is not allowed in code snippets here test it on jsfiddle");
    }
  });
  try {
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("localstorage is not allowed in code snippets here test it on jsfiddle");
  }
  if (activeTab) {
    const triggerEL = document.querySelector(`button[data-bs-target="${activeTab}"]`);
    if (triggerEl) {
      bootstrap.Tab.getOrCreateInstance(triggerEL).show()
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">Home tab content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">Profile tab content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab" tabindex="0">Contact tab content</div>
</div>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lduj2v9m/1/).